# Does not show API fetch response data in the page - React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to show a list of recipes from an API in my component when a form submitted. It doesn't show any result in the component and doesn't have any error! 
May somebody help me , What's wrong with my code ?

here is my action.js

```
import { getDataConstants } from "../_constants";
import { getDataService } from "../_service";
export const getDataAction = {
    fetchRecipes
}
function fetchRecipes(query) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loading());
        getDataService.fetchRecipes(query).then(
            response => {
                dispatch(success(response));
            },
            error =>{
                dispatch(failed(error));
            }
        )
    }
    function loading() { return { type: getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_LOADING }; }
    function success(data) { return { type: getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS, data }; }
    function failed(error) { return { type: getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_FAILED, error }; }
}
```

code for reducer.js

```
import { getDataConstants } from "../_constants";

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  items: [],
  error: null
};

export function getDataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        items: []
      };
    case getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload
      };
    case getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
        items: []
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export const getRecipes = state => state.items;
export const getRecipesloading = state => state.loading;
export const getRecipesError = state => state.error;
```

I fetch data in the service.js component

code for service.js

```
import {TIMEOUT_DELAY,HOST} from '../_constants';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getDataService = {
    fetchRecipes
}

async function fetchRecipes(query) {

  let timeout = null;
  try{
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    timeout = setTimeout(()=>{source.cancel()},TIMEOUT_DELAY);
    debugger
    const response = await axios({
      url: `${HOST}?apiKey=94be430aadf644f6a8c8c95abbcce4c1&query=${query}&_number=12`,
      method: "get",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      cancelToken: source.token
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        return response.data;
    } else {
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        return Promise.reject({isTimeout:false,error: response.data});
    }
  }catch (error) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
      return Promise.reject({isTimeout:true});
    } else {
      return Promise.reject({isTimeout:false,error});
    }
  }
}
```

code for Recipes component where API response data shown

```
const Recipes = props => {
  const { dispatch, error, loading, items } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("beef");

  const submitHandler = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(getDataAction.fetchRecipes(query));
  };
  const handleChange = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className={classes.formWidth}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className={classes.input}
        />
      </form>
      {error && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}
      {loading ? (
        <div>
          <img src={Loading} alt="Loading" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <ul className={classes.centeredDiv}>
          {items &&
            items.results.map(recipe => (
              <li
                className={classes.media}
                image={`${imgUrl}${recipe.image}`}
                title={recipe.title}
              />
            ))}
        </ul>
      )}
      }
    </>
  );
}
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      loading: getRecipesloading(state),
      items: getRecipes(state),
      error: getRecipesError(state)
    };
  };
```

Sorry about the large amount of code dumped, its just all related and I believe the error lies somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer expects `action.payload` but instead you send `action.data`. It should be:

```
case getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    items: action.data
  }
```

Comment: I changed it, but it doesn't make sense.
It is the api response, can it help?                            

`response = {results: Array(10), baseUri: "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/", offset: 0, number: 10, totalResults: 71046, …}
`

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `success` and `failed` functions like so:

```
function success(data) { 
    return { 
        type: getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS, 
        payload: data 
    }; 
}

function failed(error) { 
    return { 
        type: getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_FAILED, 
        payload: error 
    }; 
}
```

To avoid such typo problems you can create default action creator:

```
function createAction(type, payload, meta) { 
    return { 
        type: type, 
        payload: payload,
        meta: meta 
    }; 
}

// usage
function success(data) {
    return createAction(getDataConstants.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS, data)
}
```